# Colors in Andrews Curves

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pandas

I construct a pandas dataframe like so:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3), columns=['A','B', 'C'])
df['X'] = np.random.choice(['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Theta'], size=100)
```

Which gives me `df.head()`:

```
          A         B         C      X
0  2.279163 -1.790076  1.187603   Beta
1 -0.590897  0.837605 -0.606424  Alpha
2  0.448334 -1.142946  0.002507   Beta
3  0.540165 -0.204184  1.389645   Beta
4  0.105643 -1.298379 -1.404680   Beta
```

Now if I plot Andrews Curves using column 'X' -- which has one of three values -- as the class, I expect to see 100 curves with three colors, based on class X. Instead, each curve has its own color.

```
pd.tools.plotting.andrews_curves(df, 'X')
```

[image: Unexpectedly colored Andrews Curves plot from Pandas]

(The legend looks as expected, which is interesting.)

Is there a bug here or am I misunderstanding things?

Comment: smells like a bug in pandas to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following fixes the pandas code (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5378):

```
from pandas.compat import range, lrange, lmap, map, zip
from pandas.tools.plotting import _get_standard_colors
import pandas.core.common as com

def andrews_curves(data, class_column, ax=None, samples=200, colormap=None,
                   **kwds):
    """
    Parameters:
    -----------
    data : DataFrame
        Data to be plotted, preferably normalized to (0.0, 1.0)
    class_column : Name of the column containing class names
    ax : matplotlib axes object, default None
    samples : Number of points to plot in each curve
    colormap : str or matplotlib colormap object, default None
        Colormap to select colors from. If string, load colormap with that name
        from matplotlib.
    kwds : Optional plotting arguments to be passed to matplotlib

    Returns:
    --------
    ax: Matplotlib axis object

    """
    from math import sqrt, pi, sin, cos
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def function(amplitudes):
        def f(x):
            x1 = amplitudes[0]
            result = x1 / sqrt(2.0)
            harmonic = 1.0
            for x_even, x_odd in zip(amplitudes[1::2], amplitudes[2::2]):
                result += (x_even * sin(harmonic * x) +
                           x_odd * cos(harmonic * x))
                harmonic += 1.0
            if len(amplitudes) % 2 != 0:
                result += amplitudes[-1] * sin(harmonic * x)
            return result
        return f

    n = len(data)
    class_col = data[class_column]
    uniq_class = class_col.drop_duplicates()
    columns = [data[col] for col in data.columns if (col != class_column)]
    x = [-pi + 2.0 * pi * (t / float(samples)) for t in range(samples)]
    used_legends = set([])

    colors = _get_standard_colors(num_colors=len(uniq_class), colormap=colormap,
                                  color_type='random', color=kwds.get('color'))
    col_dict = dict([(klass, col) for klass, col in zip(uniq_class, colors)])
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca(xlim=(-pi, pi))
    for i in range(n):
        row = [columns[c][i] for c in range(len(columns))]
        f = function(row)
        y = [f(t) for t in x]
        label = None
        if com.pprint_thing(class_col[i]) not in used_legends:
            label = com.pprint_thing(class_col[i])
            used_legends.add(label)
            ax.plot(x, y, color=col_dict[class_col[i]], label=label, **kwds)
        else:
            ax.plot(x, y, color=col_dict[class_col[i]], **kwds)

    ax.legend(loc='upper right')
    ax.grid()
    return ax
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug, you can fix it by following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,3), columns=['A','B', 'C'])
df['X'] = np.random.choice(['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Theta'], size=100)

ax = pd.tools.plotting.andrews_curves(df, 'X')

colors = {l.get_label():l.get_color() for l in ax.lines}
for line, klass in zip(ax.lines, df["X"]):
    line.set_color(colors[klass])
```

output:

[image]